# Is log shipping good for periodic synchronization?

Tags: replication, postgresql-9.3, log-shipping

I have Postgresql 9.3 server on both my laptop and my desktop at home. I keep identical data on both system. Sometimes I work on the database on my laptop while other times I work on the database on the desktop. I want to make sure that the data and structure of both the laptop and desktop versions of the databases remain in sync. I don't need them to be hot swappable or anything, but just need to sync them once a day or once every two days.

So my question is whether log shipping is a good way to keep both databases in sync for periodic synchronizations? Or is this a bad choice since the laptop database cannot always access the desktop database from a remote location.

Answer (score 0):

It is a creative way of thinking. If you know how to handle role exchanges (promoting to primary) and do this often, it could work but I am not sure it makes you happy. Especially not because there is a bug where WALL files are prematurely recycled which makes re establishing the old primary as a slave a pain.
(this is fixed in May 2020)

Since you want to be able to work on both(I assume read and write) you have a challenge. You can only have one writable db in a replication pair.

My choice - as a dba who does this kind f things regularly - would be to set up a little RDS instance in Amazon or similar so you can access the database always, if you have a network available.
It would be different if you only need writes to one db and the others only has reads. In that case: go ahead.